# docker network device assigments

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given the following `docker-compose.yml` it is my expectation that I will find 3 network interfaces in the resulting container. But I don't know if I should expect them to be named `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2`, or in which order I should expect those assignments. If indeed the order is deterministic between deployments.

How do I safely use containers with multiple networks when there is - seemingly - no way to control and isolate which network my service listens on?

```yaml
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    networks:
    - first
    - second
    - third
 networks:
  first:
  second:
  third:
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define aliases for each network in service definition and reference alias in configurations to listen.

for example:

```
services:
  
   web:
     image: nginx
     networks:
      first:
        aliases:
          - nginx-eth0
      second:
        aliases:
          - nginx-eth1
      third:
        aliases:
          - nginx-eth2

networks:
  first:
  second:
  third:
```